# Updating an attribute on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know this is a very simple question, but I can't seem to be able to fix this despite many variations:

```
  it "will send an email" do
    invitation = Invitation.new
    invitation.email = "host@localhost.com"
    invitation.deliver 
    invitation.sent.should == true
  end
```

My model:

```
class Invitation
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :email, :type => String, :presence => true, :email => true
  field :sent, :type => Boolean, :default => false
  field :used, :type => Boolean, :default => false
  validates :email, :uniqueness => true, :email => true

  def is_registered?
    User.where(:email => email).count > 0
  end

  def deliver
    sent = true
    save
  end

end
```

This outputs:

```
  1) Invitation will send an email
     Failure/Error: invitation.sent.should == true
       expected: true
            got: false (using ==)
     # ./spec/models/invitation_spec.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

How do I set the value and then save it within the model itself?

Comment: Everything seems fine, i would recommend to try save! in your model. It seems to fail validations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `deliver` method doesn't do what you think it does:

```
def deliver
  sent = true
  save
end
```

All that does is set the local variable `sent` to `true` and then it calls `save` without anything being changed; nothing changes `self.sent` so `invitation.sent.should == true` will fail.

You want to supply an explicit receiver for the `sent=` method so that Ruby knows you don't want to assign to a local variable:

```
def deliver
  self.sent = true
  save
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I somehow was under the impression that `self` refers to the class, not the instance, but apparently not.